# Can a blunder be egregious?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives, adjective-phrases

A blunder is [by definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blunder) already a serious mistake, can we use *an egregious blunder* implying an extremely bad error?

The context:

[image]

Comment: Even the dictionary you cited has the phrase "*major* blunder" in its example sentence. Dictionaries are assembled by human beings, not gods, so it's always good to check more than one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blunder) (that you linked to) looks like the only one to emphasize the mistake as *big* or *serious* in the definition.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blunder)
[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blunder)
[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blunder)
[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blunder)

These all agree that a **blunder** is simply:

> a stupid or careless mistake

Therefore you *can* have an **egregious blunder** to mean:

> an outstandingly bad mistake caused by stupidity or carelessness

Answer (score 2):

Even if something is by definition "major," that wouldn't necessarily prevent us from adding an adjective that emphasizes that "massiveness" part of the definition even more. That's we might see, for example, references to:

- a [major catastrophe](https://www.insurancebusinessmag.com/us/news/catastrophe/cities-have-work-to-do-to-prepare-for-next-major-catastrophe-94062.aspx)
- a [colossal disaster](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/12/nyregion/small-relics-of-a-colossal-disaster.html)
- a [huge leviathan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BID4VKW)

---

But I agree with the other answer; perhaps a "blunder" is *often* a serious mistake, but not necessarily every time. A "blunder" can also connote carelessness or forgetful neglect. That's why we might even read about a [small blunder](https://www.onecountry.com/country-artists/lady-antebellum/lady-antebellum-national-anthem-save-predators/) from time to time.

By the way, [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/blunder) is a great resource for looking at multiple definitions on one page.